# How to enforce developers to resolve static code analysis tools issues before checking in to TFS

Tags: tfs, resharper, findbugs, pmd, static-code-analysis

How can we enforce developers to resolve static code analysis tools issues before they check in the file to TFS? Below are the details :-

**Source Code Repository:** TFS

**.NET/UI Static code tools:** Refactor, JSLint

**Java Web Services Code:** PMD, FindBugs

If TFS cant be configured, is it possible for us to create some kind of tool which will generate the report by taking data from all these static analysis tools daily at EOD.

Comment: TFS calls this feature ["gated check-in"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patcarna/archive/2009/06/29/an-introduction-to-gated-check-in.aspx). It can be applied to many conditions, including the tools you mention.

Comment: How about a flexible yet durable stick?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had the chance to configure it myself, but JetBrains released their ReSharper analysis engine as a set of free [command-line tools](http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2013/03/26/resharper-code-analysis-goes-beyond-visual-studio/)!

There's some information in the blog post above about how to configure the build server to run those. I assume you can configure gated check-in policy to allow check-ins only if no "major" code issues were found.